Raster calculation on 2 rasters with different size and resolution
I've got 2 raster files with different resolution and size. I want to make some calculations between the 2 rasters.
I have already tried adjusting both grids to the same size and resolution (export of each to a new raster) and then performing an operation, but without succes.
I am not a GIS expert and certainly not a programmer. Is there a simple solution for this?

Could you post the error message and some informations about the rasta datasets like origin, resolution, spatial reference?

"without succes" means you get an error or the results are not what you were hoping for? What do you want to accomplish? A result on the full extent of the bigger raster, just the intersection, what resolution, what software are you using..It is not clear...help us so we can help you

Both rasters have the same CRS. I want to performe a calculation (I need to add the values of both) between the 2 rasters using the Rastercalculator in QGIS. The big raster has a resolution grid of 100x100m, 703 colums, 590 lines. The small raster has a resolution of 25x25m, 205 colums, 151 lines. As a results, I want to obtain a raster on the full extent of the big raster. I suppose that I have to put both rasters on a same resolution and that I have to define the empty values surounding the small raster? At this moment I don't know what's the best procedure to achieve this. Thank you!
